# Run an exe from inside a Windows Service with elevated privileges

Tags: delphi, winapi, service

I have a Windows Service created with Delphi. Please, how can I run an exe, in the token of the logged user (interactive), as another admin user, with elevated privileges? Is it even possible? Of course, I know the admin username and password. Thanks!

I tried these 2 functions:

```
function WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId: ULONG; var phToken: THandle): BOOL;
  stdcall; external 'Wtsapi32.dll';

function RunApp(const Path: string): Boolean;
var
  ACSId: DWORD;
  Token: THandle;
  SInfo: TStartupInfo;
  PInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not FileExists(Path) then Exit;
  ACSId := WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionID;
  if (ACSId = $FFFFFFFF) then Exit;
  if WTSQueryUserToken(ACSId, Token) then
  try
    ZeroMemory(@SInfo, SizeOf(SInfo));
    SInfo.cb := SizeOf(SInfo);
    SInfo.lpDesktop := PChar('WinSta0\Default');
    SInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    SInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    ZeroMemory(@PInfo, SizeOf(PInfo));
    Result := CreateProcessAsUserW(Token, nil, PChar(Path), nil, nil, False,
      NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS or CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, nil, nil, SInfo, PInfo);
    if Result then
    begin
      CloseHandle(PInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(PInfo.hThread);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(Token);
  end;
end;
```

```
function RunAppAsUser(const Path, User, Pswd: string): Boolean;
var
  Token: THandle;
  SInfo: TStartupInfo;
  PInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  Result := False;
  if FileExists(Path) then
  try
    if LogonUser(PWideChar(User), '', PWideChar(Pswd),
      LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, Token) then
    try
      ZeroMemory(@SInfo, SizeOf(SInfo));
      SInfo.cb := SizeOf(SInfo);
      SInfo.lpDesktop := PChar('WinSta0\Default');
      SInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      SInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
      ZeroMemory(@PInfo, SizeOf(PInfo));
      Result := CreateProcessAsUserW(Token, nil, PChar(Path), nil, nil, False,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS or CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, nil, nil, SInfo, PInfo);
//      Result := CreateProcessAsUser(Token, nil, PChar(Path), nil, nil, False,
//        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS or CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, nil, nil, SInfo, PInfo);
      if Result then
      begin
        CloseHandle(PInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(PInfo.hThread);
      end else
        RaiseLastOSError;
    finally
      CloseHandle(Token);
    end else
      RaiseLastOSError;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Log(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

The first function works great but the exe runs without elevated privileges. The second function didn't return any error, but the exe never runs.

Comment: The 2nd function doesn't run the process in the user's session, like the 1st function does. Try using `SetTokenInformation()` to apply the user's session ID to the token you logged into before giving the token to `CreateProcessAsUserW()`

Comment: instead `WTSQueryUserToken` use self token ( `OpenProcessToken`  + `DuplicateTokenEx` + set session id in token)

Comment: @RbMm, please, what `ProcessHandle` to use with `OpenProcessToken` in order to get the current logged user token? When using `GetCurrentProcess`, my exe runs in the same SYSTEM account as the service.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for your comment, but I think RbMm approach will be easier to implement, once I do not need to include admin logon username and password.

Comment: i say - you need set sessionId in token. in this case your process will be run in this session and interactive. with localsystem token

Comment: @RbMm the calling process is a service running as SERVICE, so using the calling process' token will run the spawned process as SYSTEM, not as a specific (admin) user. Running a SYSTEM process in a user session is rarely a good idea

Comment: @Cristian What RbMm suggested is no simpler than what I suggested. If you don't use `WTSQueryUserToken()`, you would need to manually set the target session ID in whatever token handle you obtain from elsewhere. Also, to do what RbMm is suggesting, you would have to call `OpenProcess()` with `GetCurrentProcessId()` and then pass that process `HANDLE` to `OpenProcessToken()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau of course token will be from LocalSystem (if service run under this account) but process will be in user terminal session and can be interactive. here question - what really need for OP ? run interactive process from service elevated ? or run exactly as current active user ? what if user not admin at all ? if admin - we can get elevated linked token for session. but for not admin - it not exist. OP need say - what (for what) he really need

Comment: @RemyLebeau OpenProcess() with GetCurrentProcessId() of course not need - simply use pseudohandle for current process (-1)

Comment: Sorry about delay, programming is a hobbie yet. Well, `OpenProcessToken` (with `GetCurrentProcess`) + DuplicateTokenEx solved the problem, despite the exe is running as SERVICE. @RemyLebeau I can't figure out a solution using `SetTokenInformation`, please can you give us some exemple code? Thank you!

Comment: @Cristian `SetTokenInformation(Token, TokenSessionId, @SessionId, sizeof(SessionId));`